# Difference between SurfaceView implementation on different Android versions

Tags: android, surfaceview

I’ve been told by my supervisor that there is a significant difference between the `SurfaceView` implementation for 4.0 and above (or it might be a different, but a 3.0+ version) and other versions; in the older implementations, a `SurfaceView` supposedly isn’t really a `View` and has some limitations with putting other UI elements on top of it, whereas in the newer versions, this is fixed.

After some research, I still don’t see it - the difference, that is. Are there really any significant differences between the older/newer implementation of `SurfaceView`, other than hardware acceleration and natural code improvements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a SurfaceView supposedly isn’t really a View and has some limitations with putting other UI elements on top of it

This is somewhat true and has not really changed AFAIK.

> whereas in the newer versions, this is fixed

It is more that there is now `TextureView`, which can be used in place of `SurfaceView` in many cases. `TextureView` takes advantage of the GPU to offer both a `Surface` (e.g., for playing video) and participate as a regular `View` more (e.g., for animations).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (love your book, BTW)!

Comment: @user2965896: Thanks for the kind words!